# Why does Camel throw an exception on FTP reply 125?

Tags: exception, ftp, zos, camel-ftp

```
...
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed:
    125 Storing data set TEST.TRANSFER.FB80.TXT
 IOException caught while copying.. Code: 125
  at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.doStoreFile(FtpOperations.java:710)
  ...
```

[RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959#page-40) reads:

> ```
> 125   Data connection already open; transfer starting.
> ```

This is more informational rather than exceptional, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTP reply code 125 is just half of the story. Performing the transfer with Windows 7's command line `ftp` client  manually shows:

```
ftp> send TRANSFER.FB80.TXT
---> PORT 10,100,113,251,254,235
200 Port request OK.
---> STOR TRANSFER.FB80.TXT
125 Storing data set TEST.TRANSFER.FB80.TXT
451-Error: Name=CkResults (Write) RC=-13
451-System completion code and reason: B37-04
451-Data set is out of space.
451-Error (1013) closing the data set.
451 Transfer aborted due to file error.
...
```

I created the according issue [CAMEL-13069: Display proper FTP reply message in case of transfer error](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13069).